# How to retrieve a safearray (of struct) from COM object via ColdFusion 9

Tags: com, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, safearray, createobject

I am attempting to reference a COM object method defined as:

```
IEdmFile7::GetDerivedBOMs  
Returns the derived (a.k.a. "named" or "saved") bills of materials associated with this file.  
Prototype:

HRESULT GetDerivedBOMs( [out,ref] SAFEARRAY ( struct EdmBomInfo ) *ppoBoms );
```

I have a reference to the IEdmFile7 object in the edmFile variable.

When I `<cfdump var="#edmFile#">` the method is visible as:

```
Method: GetDerivedBOMs([out]USERDEFINED, [out, retval]VOID)
```

When I attempt to call the method (have tried passing lots of different param types):

```
<cfset edmFile.GetDerivedBOMs(???)>
```

It errors with `AutomationException: Member not found`.  I can only presume it is not recognizing or casting the param correctly. How do I pass a reference to a safearray(of struct) correctly to the method?

**(Edit from comments)**

Some examples of what I've tried:

```
 <cfset myObject = createObject("java","java.lang.Object").init()> 
 <cfset myArray = arrayNew(1)> 
 <cfset myRefArrayOfObjects = javaCast("java.lang.Object[]", myArray)> 
 <cfset myResultArray = edmFile.GetDerivedBOMs(myRefArrayOfObjects)>
```

Result:

```
 Member Not Found Description: Automation Exception: Member Not Found
```

Another attempt from the comments:

```
<cfset myArray = ArrayNew(1)> 
<cfset myArray = edmFile.GetDerivedBOMs()>
```

Result:

```
There are no methods with the specified method name and argument types. 
Check your function and retry
```

Comment: It would help if you could show us the calls and params that you have tried and the error that was generated with each.  And did you try setting a variable with your example?  Like `<cfset edmResult = edmFile.GetDerivedBOMs()>` and then dump the `edmResult` variable.

Comment: In re-reading your example, why are you passing anything to that method? The safearray parameter is marked as an output only.  Right? So have you tried `<cfset myArray = ArrayNew(1)>` then `<cfset myArray = edmFile.GetDerivedBOMs()>` and then dump the `myArray` variable.

Comment: Miguel-F: I have tried so may things I couldn't post em all...  Your suggestion (i.e. <cfset myArray = ArrayNew(1)> then <cfset myArray = edmFile.GetDerivedBOMs()> ) returned: "There are no methods with the specified method name and argument types. Check your function and retry"

Comment: Other examples of what I've tried:    <cfset myObject = createObject("java","java.lang.Object").init()>
  <cfset myArray = arrayNew(1)>
  <cfset myRefArrayOfObjects = javaCast("java.lang.Object[]", myArray)>
  <cfset myResultArray = edmFile.GetDerivedBOMs(myRefArrayOfObjects)>
Result: Member Not Found  Description: Automation Exception: Member Not Found

Comment: Miguel-F:  I think a parameter is required because it is expecting a variable passed by reference, which it can populate.  The result (i.e. the second parameter described as [out, retval]VOID is what would end up in the variable my result = blah.  It is just a value of 1 or 0 (i.e. true or false...  did the function succeed.)

Comment: Are you getting a stack trace when the error occurs?  If so, can you include that here.  Also, when commenting here on SO if you prefix the person's id with the character '@' it will notify them of the comment. Like this for me @Miguel-F  Just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's a .net interop limitation.  From the CF docs

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec13e1a-7fd4.html

- You cannot invoke methods with pointers as arguments or the return
  type.
- You cannot invoke methods that take Out parameters.

In this case you're hitting both of those with a byref address[pointer] of a variable of type safearray that it will create and return to you as an OUT parameter.

In cases like this I've found it easier to create a .net class to "wrap" around this to act as an intermediary that accounts for the issues that CF has with doing this.